# Use non-blocking FIFO as a ring-buffer?

Tags: c, nonblocking, fifo, circular-buffer

I have created a FIFO where I can do non-blocking writes into in this way:

```
// others, searching for a non-blocking FIFO-writer may copy this ;-)
mkfifo("/tmp/myfifo", S_IRWXU);
int fifo_fd = open("/tmp/myfifo", O_RDWR);
fcntl(fifo_fd, F_SETFL, fcntl(fifo_fd, F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK);

// and then in a loop:
LOGI("Writing into fifo.");
if (write(fifo_fd, data, count) < 0) {
    LOGE("Failed to write into fifo: %s", strerror(errno));
}
```

The non-blocking write works perfect, but due to my logging I can see:

```
(..)
Writing into fifo.
Writing into fifo.
Writing into fifo.
Failed to write into fifo: Try again    
Writing into fifo.
Failed to write into fifo: Try again    
Writing into fifo.
Failed to write into fifo: Try again
```

After I created a reader like `cat /tmp/myfifo > foo.out`, the error goes away.

I thought the FIFO works like a ring-buffer and drops the first-written bytes when the buffer is full. But now I have learned that it blocks/prevents new bytes until the first bytes are read.

Does anyone know a simple other way or additional operation I can make so that the FIFO behaves like a ring-buffer?

Comment: You can probably get a fimfo by reading yourself.  Quite a randomizer of data, hard to see how the reader could ever get meaningful data.

Comment: Hm, yes that may be a solution.. I have to think about if that is possible in my case. Thank you!